# Do we know which companies donated to Bitcoin Core development?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development

Similar to a previous question ([How do the people who work on Bitcoin Core get paid?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/62141/how-do-the-people-who-work-on-bitcoin-core-get-paid/62142#62142)) which I felt does not adequately answer my interest.

Do we know specifically which developers are drawing a salary from donations and which companies are making these donations.  The reason for my question is to figure out if there might be any conflict of interest in their work.

As we have seen in politics the decisions of politicians is heavily persuaded by their campaign contributions and the scaling debate of Bitcoin as a "store of value" vs BCH (and others) as having "utility" is a heated one and I think this information will shed some light on the intentions of the developers.